# How to check if directory exist or not on passing as a parameter in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to pass the directory as a parameter and checking its existence -

```py
    def validatePath(DirectoryName):
        pathtodata="/temp/project/data/"
        if os.path.exists('pathtodata'DirectoryName):
           return True
        return False
    
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("DirectoryName", nargs='?', help="Input folder Name", type=str)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    myDir = args.DirectoryName
    validatePath(myDir)
```

Error : Syntax Error in line os.path.exists('pathtodata'DirectoryName):

Comment: I think that should be os.path.exists(os.path.join(pathtodata, DirectoryName))

Comment: what is your checking directory `DirectoryName or pathtodata` ? join the directory `pathtodata'DirectoryName+/+DirectoryName`

Comment: One of the reason you get downvotes is that your code dos not run, fix that first, rethink the solution, and ask the question again. When somebody tries to run your code they will get a SyntaxError

Comment: @TomRon - thanks, this is what I was looking for, could you please add this as an answer too.

Comment: @Cleared - My code is showing syntax error in a line for which I didn't know how to use, the whole idea to post the question is to get the idea how to combine the path and it exists "os.path.exists('pathtodata'DirectoryName)", If I could have solved that syntaxError I wouldn't be asking the question in first place, let me know if that makes sense?

Comment: @pyd - Thanks! my checking directory was `DirectoryName`, your solution worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python the way you combine paths is not `'pathtodata'DirectoryName` but rather `os.path.join(pathtodata, DirectoryName)`.

Comment: Thanks, @John. I got it now, first I need to combine the path and then validate its existence.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `os.path.join()`:

Your code should look like:

```
def validatePath(DirectoryName):
    pathtodata="/temp/project/data/"
    pathtodir = os.path.join(parthtodata, DirectoryName)
    if os.path.exists(pathtodir):
       return True
    return False

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("DirectoryName", nargs='?', help="Input folder Name", type=str)
args = parser.parse_args()
myDir = args.DirectoryName
validatePath(myDir):
```

Comment: You may also wish to verify that [`os.path.isdir(pathtodir)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.isdir) is true, to make sure it's a directory and not a regular file.

Comment: Thanks, @holdenweb, I was not aware of `isdir` function, Currently in a learning phase.

Answer (score 1):

The `os.path.join` joins the paths according to your os delimiter and the `os.path.exists` checks if the path exists.

```
os.path.exists(os.path.join(pathtodata, DirectoryName))
```

What caused the syntax error earlier was

```
'pathtodata'DirectoryName
```

which is invalid python syntax regardless to the context.

More details in os.path documentation - https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html